# Vue 2.x Transitions not working with Html Tag Id CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

Just curious if this is expected behavior with vue, or maybe there is some underlying CSS logic I'm not seeing?

- The following Vue transition works when the default 'right' property is set with a class selector

`.theBoxClass { right: 100px;}`

but not when set using a css ID selector

`#theBoxId { right: 100px;}`

**CodePen**
https://codepen.io/PhilipNameHere/pen/xxwBWxw

**Code**

```
<div id="background"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue">
  <transition name="slide">
    <div id="theBoxId" class="box" v-if="show">ID</div>
  </transition>

  <transition name="slide">
    <div class="theBoxClass box" v-if="show">Class</div>
  </transition>
  <button v-on:click="onShowClick">CLICK ME TWICE</button>
</div>


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:20px;  
}

button
{
  background:red;
  padding:30px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.box{
   background:gray;
  width:100px;  
  position:fixed;  
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:100px;  
}
.theBoxClass
{
  top:20px;
  right:100px;
}

#theBoxId
{
   top:220px;
   right:100px;
}


    .slide-enter-active , 
    .slide-leave-active {
      transition: right 1s ease-out;    
    }

    .slide-enter,
    .slide-leave-to  { 
       right:-100px;
    }



new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {  
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    onShowClick: function() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
.slide-enter,
.slide-leave-to  { 
   right:-100px;
}
```

To

```
.slide-enter,
.slide-leave-to  { 
   right:-100px !important;
}
```

Makes it work with the ID because ID selectors have greater [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than class selectors:

> The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
>
> • Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., ::before).
>
> • Class selectors, attributes selectors and pseudo-classes.
>
> • ID selectors (e.g., #example).